# Livewire @entangle

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am new to Livewire and have a question.

In my Livewire blade I have a JS function that calls a component method which updates $this->questions.

```
    function QuestionBatchRequest() {
        Livewire.emit('moreQuestions');
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('moreQuestions'));
    }
```

This works as I can output to an input box and see the data change.

I then have

```
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {

        window.livewire.on('QuestionBatchListener', () => {
            let data = @entangle('questions');
            myUnityInstance.SendMessage("JS-Unity", "InjectQuizData", data);
        });

    });
```

How can I get the updated $this->questions to my JS variable directly?

This is in my method in my component

```
$this->questions = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$this->emit('QuestionBatchListener');
```

This function is called from my Unity game on the same page. The initial set of questions is received on page load and works fine.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I changed

```
let data = @entangle('questions');
```

with

```
let data = @this.get('questions');
```

...

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Please accept it to resolve the question.